# Convert a sequential number to letter in HiveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a column in my table with the following structure:

```
column_1
1233042
2233098
5230980
```

I need to replace the first number to a letter:

```
column_1
A233042
B233098
E230980
```

The range of numbers are 1-9, then the letters will be A-I.

Is there a way to do it without using CASE statement for each number in Hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use such a combination of functions :

```
SELECT DECODE(UNHEX(HEX(SUBSTR(column_1,1,1)+64)), 'US-ASCII')||
       SUBSTR(column_1,1-LENGTH(column_1)) 
  FROM t
```

where the first character replacement conforms to ASCII conversion logic(65->A,66->B,69->E...)